# Return vs. Risk Graphing web site alternatives to RiskGrades, which is closing?

Tags: stocks, mutual-funds, online-tools, risk, investing

Risk Grades' free website (riskgrades.com) is closing 6-30-11.  Do you know of a similar site that allows the user to enter several ticker symbols (funds or stocks) and obtain a graph showing relative return and risk?  Thanks,  George

Comment: They use standard deviation to quantify risk, so someone could modify the spreadsheet I talk about here: http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/8900/standard-deviation-with-asset-prices

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the www.sinkorswim.com desktop/web [application](https://www.thinkorswim.com/tos/displayPage.tos?webpage=softwareLobby&displayFormat=hide)? I opened a "virtual" account with them and started using it. Don't fill out all of the registration forms, all that is needed is the username/password info.

The software is very powerful and does complex analytics. (look under the ***"Application Tools"*** tab for list of software features). And to specifically address your question, they have risk analysis built into the sofware (see [screen shot](https://www.thinkorswim.com/tos/client/products/software/thinkDesktop/screenShot.jsp?img=AnalyzeTab)).

I would also recommend trying either of these [tools](http://www.samoasky.com/protfolio/) from SamoaSky. I haven't used them much, but they are worth 20 minutes to see if they are what you're looking for.